# Python - parallel construction of a matrix

Tags: python, parallel-processing

What is the correct method in python to parallelize the creation of a large sparse matrix M? Ideally each thread would be responsible for setting values for a subset of the rows. The resulting matrix will be input to a classifier. Does the python global interpreter lock prevent efficient parallelization?

Assume an input list I composed of tuples (i, j, k). The desire is to set M[i,j] = k for all tuples in I.

```
M = scipy.sparse.dok_matrix((num_rows, num_cols))
for i, j, k in I:
    M[i, j] = k
```

Comment: This is rather open-ended a question; there are many ways to do parallelism. My personal stock one is ipython-parallel, but you should look into tutorials rather than ask here.

Comment: *"Does the python global interpreter lock prevent efficient parallelization?"* Yes, it does.

Comment: How large is your dataset? As in how many matrix rows are you trying to process?

Comment: 1 billion rows x 10K columns

Answer (score 0):

In theory all updates to the matrix can be done concurrently, supposing the list of tuples does not contain inconsistent data, i.e. each matrix element is set at most once.

When GIL is out of the way and the matrix can be shared among any number of threads, then all this boils down to whether scipy.sparse.dok_matrix is capable of accepting concurrent updates.

Unfortunately neither scipy.sparse.dok_matrix documentation nor http://wiki.scipy.org/ParallelProgramming seems to answer this.